# Horizontal lines appear when using Apple Pencil on iPad while charging

Tags: ipad, apple-pencil

While charging my iPad Pro (running iOS 14.0) from my MacBook, using a [Syncwire lightning cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Syncwire-Lightning-iPhone-Charger-Cable-White/dp/B07M8SG1JX/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&qid=1601399021&refinements=p_89%3ASyncwire&s=computers&sr=1-1), random horizontal lines appear when I draw using my Apple Pencil. Has anyone encountered this problem, or have any advice on how to fix it?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like the kind of glitch you get with a poorly-rectified power supply. Are you using an Apple PSU from a regular mains supply? I've only ever seen similar when charging in the car, using an inverter from 12v to 240v then a regular 240v Apple PSU. The rectifier in that case is to blame, for poor conversion to AC. The symptom kind of feels like someone else has an invisible finger on the screen.

Comment: The iPad Pro scans the capacitive touch screen at 120 Hz - so that is a mighty short bust of feedback causing it. I agree - look at isolating the cable / charger as it's clearly happening for you to catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution to my own problem, so posting it here in case others have the same issue.

I have been charging my iPad from my Macbook, which was also charging at the same time. As soon as I remove my Macbook from its power source, the issue disappears. It seems that the AC power entering the Macbook was somehow interfering with the iPad!